# Check if Environment Variable exists for an user with su

Tags: environment-variables, su

I'm on it since days, I need to check for an user $1 if an Environnement Variable $2 exists.

I tried some cases :

```
 $ [[ -v a ]] && echo "a ok" || echo "a no"
 a no
 $ [[ -v $HOME ]] && echo "a ok" || echo "a no"
 a no
```

(So nope (I tried on Bash > 4.2))

```
if [ su - ${1} -c "[ -z "${2}" ]" ]
```

Now, I'm trying this approach because I don't find what's wrong :/ !

```
su - root -c "echo "$HOME" | wc | cut -d' ' -f2"
su - root -c "echo "$HOME" | wc | sed 's/ //g'"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax in your first examples is incorrect.  If you write:

```
[[ -v $HOME ]]
```

Then you are actually executing the command:

```
[[ -v /home/yourusername ]]
```

Which of course is going to fail.  You want:

```
[[ -v HOME ]] && echo ok || echo no
```

You can combine that with `su` to get:

```
su - root -c "[[ -v HOME ]]" && echo ok || echo no
```

Your last examples won't work because you can't nest quotes, and because shell variable expansion happens before command execution.  That is, given:

```
su - root -c "echo "$HOME" | wc | cut -d' ' -f2"
```

The command you execute is actually going to be:

```
su - root -c 'echo /home/somesuser | ...'
```

If you want the value of `$HOME` from the perspective of `root`, you would need to prevent variable expansion in the local shell, for example by using single quotes:

```
su - root -c 'echo $HOME | ...'
```

It's not clear to me why you're passing the output to `wc`, because the word count of `$HOME` is almost always going to be `1`.  Rather than post-processing the output of `wc` with `sed` or `cut`, you can just use the `-w` option to get the word count:

```
su - root -c 'echo $HOME | wc -w'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sure, I always forgot to escape my var... Sry.

    su - root -c "[[ -v HOME ]]" && echo ok || echo no

Doesn't work
    $ su - root -c "[[ -v HOME ]]" && echo ok || echo no
    -sh: -c: line 0: conditional binary operator expected
    -sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near `HOME'
    -sh: -c: line 0: `[[ -v HOME ]]'

For 

    su - root -c 'echo $HOME | ...'

I took the habit to escape the var like that

    su - root -c "echo \$HOME | ..."
I don't know which one is the best practice.

And omg I didn't think about wc -w ! It does what I wanted to ! Thx